# Java reference-aware cache

Tags: java, caching, finalize

I have memory-expensive objects, that sometimes come with identical content. I would like to cache them as long as they're referenced at least once, and evict from the cache if all referenced are destroyed. Is there a standard solution for that in Java?

Concretely, I would like to achieve something like the following: 
`ExpObject` can be referenced by multiple instances of `Entry`, and each `Entry` can be contained in multiple collections. (any other references to `ExpObject`'s don't need to be tracked). 
When an `Entry` is created, we check whether there is already an equal `ExpObject` and if so, return the cached copy. Otherwise we cache and return the new object. The corresponding reference counter is incremented. 
Finally, when all referenced to `Entry` are gone and it gets collected, the reference counter in `ExpObject` is decremented, and if it happened to be the last `Entry` that pointed to this `ExpObject`, then the `ExpObject` is evicted from the cache. 
However, this solution relies on the `finalize()` method, that I've been told I shouldn't rely on.

```
class ExpObject {
    private final static Map<ExpObject, ExpObject> cache = new HashMap<>();
    private String longString; //stand-in for large content 
    private int referenced = 0;
    
    public static getExpObject(String content) {
        ExpObject newObject = new ExpObject(content);
        if (cache.containsKey(newObject)){
            ExpObject cachedCopy = cache.get(newObject);
            cachedCopy.referenced++;
            return cachedCopy;
        } else {
            newObject.referenced++;
            cache.put(newObject, newObject);
            return newObject;
        }
    }
    
    private ExpObject(String content){
        this.content = content;
    }
    
    public void decrementReference(){
        this.referenced--;
        if (this.referenced <= 0){
            cache.remove(this);
        }
    }
}

class Entry {
    private ExpObject expObject;
    
    public Entry(String content){
        expObject = ExpObject.getExpObject(content);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void finalize(){
        expObject.decrementReference();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would look at using `java.lang.ref.SoftReference`s to implement the cache.

Comment: You want to use weak references (soft references are if you want to cache after zero references, but imposes higher GC overhead). Caffeine's weak key/value cache would fit your requirements.